# Using Javascript on SVG elements in order to create mouse events

Tags: javascript, svg, mouseevent

I have an SVG code that looks like this:

```js
 <svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="45" width="142" y="59.20001" x="59.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffaaaa"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="56" width="142" y="217.20001" x="97.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff007f"/>
  <rect id="svg_3" height="53" width="172" y="123.20001" x="360.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff7f00"/>
 </g>
 </svg>
```

And I want to use Javascript to make all the individual rectangles move slightly when I click them. Or show a picture of something when I hover the cursor over them. 
I managed to do it with CSS, but I am really interested in using Javascript for these things, but I have no clue. Thank you!

Comment: Take a loot at [`d3.js`](https://d3js.org/). It makes doing SVG animation super super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vanilla JavaScript starting point. **Update**: Comments throughout the code explain what is going on.

```js
var shapes = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); // find all the shapes by making a collection of them
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i += 1) { // tell the program what function (i.e. what handler)...
  shapes[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler); // ...to run every time each shape is clicked
}

function clickHandler(event) { // the function to run when any shape is clicked
    // 'event' holds a lot of info, but critical here is 'which shape was clicked', i.e. event.target
  var inc = 4, iter = 0; // set the anim'n speed and the count of anim'n steps
  var jiggle = function() { // the function to perform on each animation cycle
    iter += 1; // increment the anim'n step count
    if (iter > 64) return; // when enough anim'n steps have run, do nothing more
    event.target.x.baseVal.value += inc; // animate! : change the shape's left pos'n
    if ((iter + 2) % 4 === 0) inc = -inc; // every 4 steps, change the move dir'n
    requestAnimationFrame(jiggle); // at the end of every anim'n step, do it all again
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(jiggle); // get the first step of the anim'n going
};
```

```html
<p>Click the shapes</p>
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="45" width="142" y="59.20001" x="59.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffaaaa"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="56" width="142" y="217.20001" x="97.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff007f"/>
  <rect id="svg_3" height="53" width="172" y="123.20001" x="360.39999" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff7f00"/>
 </g>
 </svg>
```